# How to customize searchable fields with selector in gridjs

Tags: javascript, gridjs, js-search

In `gridjs` there is an the example of using `selector` in [search](https://gridjs.io/docs/examples/search) field.

```
const grid = new Grid({
  columns: [
   {
     name: 'Name',
     formatter: (cell) => cell.firstName
   }, 
   'Email',
   'Phone Number'
  ],
  search: {
    selector: (cell, rowIndex, cellIndex) => cellIndex === 0 ? cell.firstName : cell
  },
  data: [
    [{ firstName: 'John', lastName: 'MP' }, 'john@example.com', '(353) 01 222 3333'],
    [{ firstName: 'Mark', lastName: 'Blue' }, 'mark@gmail.com',   '(01) 22 888 4444'],
  ]
});
```

But from the example it's not quite clear how to reduce search to only `'Email'` and `'Phone Number'` fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify a selector to which the search is going to run against. In the example, it's specified as the `firstName` as long as the search is running against the first cell, i.e., the line `cellIndex === 0`. Thus, if you want to have the search run against a specific cell/column, you'd have to write a conditional for its specific cell location/index.

Here is an example that filters based on `Email` & `Phone Number`:

```js
const grid = new Grid({
  columns: [
   {
     name: 'Name',
     formatter: (cell) => cell.firstName
   }, 
   'Email',
   'Phone Number'
  ],
  search: {
    selector: (cell, rowIndex, cellIndex) => {
      if (cellIndex === 1) return cell;
      
      if (cellIndex === 2) return cell;
    }
  },
  data: [
    [{ firstName: 'John', lastName: 'MP' }, 'john@example.com', '(353) 01 222 3333'],
    [{ firstName: 'Mark', lastName: 'Blue' }, 'mark@gmail.com',   '(01) 22 888 4444'],
  ]
});
```

Or for conciseness:

```js
const grid = new Grid({
  columns: [
   {
     name: 'Name',
     formatter: (cell) => cell.firstName
   }, 
   'Email',
   'Phone Number'
  ],
  search: {
    selector: (cell, rowIndex, cellIndex) => {
        if (cellIndex !== 0) return cell;
    }
  },
  data: [
    [{ firstName: 'John', lastName: 'MP' }, 'john@example.com', '(353) 01 222 3333'],
    [{ firstName: 'Mark', lastName: 'Blue' }, 'mark@gmail.com',   '(01) 22 888 4444'],
  ]
});
```

In the latter example, I match the search selector against all the cell indices/fields except for the first cell(Name field). Hope this helps! :)